# Hdfs balancer not working

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-2.7.2

I'm sure nobody started the balancing, what could be wrong?

Balancing run thus:
`# 
    hdfs  balancer -threshold 1
    16/02/19 15:10:02 INFO balancer.Balancer: Using a threshold of 1.0
    16/02/19 15:10:02 INFO balancer.Balancer: namenodes  =  [hdfs://m1.h.c.test:8020, hdfs://m1.h.c.test]
    16/02/19 15:10:02 INFO balancer.Balancer: parameters = Balancer.Parameters [BalancingPolicy.Node, threshold = 1.0, max idle iteration = 5, #excluded nodes = 0, #included nodes = 0, #source nodes = 0, run during upgrade = false]
    16/02/19 15:10:02 INFO balancer.Balancer: included nodes = []
    16/02/19 15:10:02 INFO balancer.Balancer: excluded nodes = []
    16/02/19 15:10:02 INFO balancer.Balancer: source nodes = []
    Time Stamp               Iteration#  Bytes Already Moved  Bytes Left To    Move  Bytes Being Moved
    java.io.IOException: Another Balancer is running..  Exiting ...`

I use hdp packages:

    `ii  hadoop-2-3-2-0-2950               2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950

    ii  hadoop-2-3-2-0-2950-client        2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950

    ii  hadoop-2-3-2-0-2950-hdfs          2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950

    ii  hadoop-2-3-2-0-2950-hdfs-namenode 2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950`

Comment: Do you have multiple name nodes?

Comment: I have 1 nn, 1 sn and 3 dn.

Comment: Understood, it was necessary to run the command like so:                      hdfs  balancer -fs hdfs://m1.h.c.test:8020/

Comment: Glad it worked. Generally the remote NN should be specified in the configuration file. What is your fs.defaultFS config in your `core-site.xml`? I also found your original post, the `namenodes` was configured as [hdfs://m1.h.c.test:8020, hdfs://m1.h.c.test].

Comment: <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://m1.h.c.test</value>

Answer (score 3):

You can try:
`hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash /system/balancer.id`

Answer (score 2):

It can also be problem described in
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-8897 
- this is specific to HDFS HA configuration.

Issue fixed in HDFS 2.8 and 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following command to kill the process.

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'balancer' | awk '{print $2}')
```

And then run balancer using Ambari.

In case you are using HA environment, first find out where the process is running by using,

```
hdfs dfs -cat /system/balancer.id
```

Comment: Hmm, that question was answered three years ago (in the comments).